# keep second form on the same level as the first form

Tags: c#, winforms, topmost, toplevel

I want to make the second form in the same toplevel as the first form and vice versa, only by entering one of the forms, so i put both of these in each forms' `Enter` event: the `Show` method is called in the Form1 `Load` event, so the second form always show up when the application is started.

```
private void Form1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.TopMost = true;
    }
```

and in form 2:

```
private void Form2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 frm1 = new Form1();
        frm1.TopMost = true;
    }
```

but even though when i select one of the forum or bring focus, the other stays in the background, how to make them always on the same level ?

Comment: look up the difference between the following `Form.Show() and Form.ShowModal()` also if this is `MDI` then you will need to understand the difference between `Parent & Owner`

Comment: @MethodMan....what ? how would the show methods have any difference on this ? do you mean by calling the show method it'll get the second/first form to the top ? i edited my question to be far clear

Comment: Windows are stacked.  If you want them on "the same level" then you have to make them small enough so you can put them next to each other.  Stop using TopMost.

Comment: @HansPassant i already got that part figured out, what i mean't is, how to make one form the topmost, while the otehr one is one level behind, since the windows are next to each other, if you get what i mean.

Comment: If you mean that you want both windows to have focus, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @RenniePet yes it's pretty much impossible, what i want is, when one window is in forcus (normaly it's on top of everything), the other one would be second from top.

Comment: Do the two forms have a way of referencing each other? If so, when you detect that Formx has gotten focus (been "entered"), then try "other.Focus();" followed by "this.Focus();".

Comment: @RenniePet it is still not working, it doesn't bring focus to either forms

Comment: Hmm, how about "??.Activate();" followed by "??.BringToFront();" followed by "??.Focus();", first for the other form and then for the current form. (Yes, I'm grasping at straws. If this doesn't work I'm afraid I've run out of suggestions.)

Comment: @RenniePet thank you for everything, it seems not to do the trick aswell, i'll just have to work with it like this, thank you again