# How do I create a second page in WinForm that stays in the same window as the first one?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-6.0

I have been trying various methods to bring this form forward and another method to make the first forms controls invisible. I have the following source code
This is the Homeworkagenda.cs Program.

```
namespace assignment_manager_source
{
    public partial class HomeworkAgenda : Form
    {
        public HomeworkAgenda()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.IsMdiContainer = true;
        }

        private void btnclick_createclass(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnclick_nxtpage(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var classes_Nxt = new Classes();
            classes_Nxt.MdiParent = this;
            classes_Nxt.Show();
            classes_Nxt.BringToFront();
        }

    }
}
```

This is the HomeworkAgendaDesigner.cs.

```
using System.Drawing;

namespace assignment_manager_source
{
    partial class HomeworkAgenda
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        public Label assignments;
        public Label class_designation;
        public Label class_holder;
        public Label assignment_holder;
        public TextBox assignment_name;
        public TextBox class_name;
        public Button creation_assignment;
        public Button creation_class;
        public Button nxt_page;

        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 450);
            this.Text = "Homework Agenda";
            this.class_holder = new Label
            {
                Location = new Point(50, 50),
                Text = "Class Name: ",
                AutoSize = true
            };
            this.assignment_holder = new Label 
            {
                Location = new Point(50,75),
                Text = "Assignment Name: ",
                AutoSize = true
            };
            this.nxt_page = new Button
            {
                Location = new Point(Bottom, 100),
                Text = "Next Page",
                AutoSize = true,
                
            };
            nxt_page.Click += btnclick_nxtpage;
            Controls.Add(this.class_holder);
            Controls.Add(this.assignment_holder);
            Controls.Add(this.nxt_page);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is my second form which I am using it is the Classes.Designer.cs:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace assignment_manager_source
{
    partial class Classes
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        public Button backbtn_add;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            backbtn_add = new Button
            {
                Location = new Point(Bottom, 15),
                Text = "Back",
                AutoSize = true

            };
            Controls.Add(backbtn_add);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

I also implemented a Classes.cs Program that does the following:

```
namespace assignment_manager_source
{
    public partial class Classes : Form
    {
        public Classes()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

My end goal is trying to make seem as if a user is just on one window and moving in between pages. I aim to support functionality to pass data back and forth between page and display things to user. Any guidance on how I could scheme to design my application would be appreciated. The main issue that when I click the next button it opens a small window and to see the button one has to maximize. I read this question and it is 8 years old I am attaching because it is relevant.

[Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29477836/keep-second-form-on-the-same-level-as-the-first-form)

Comment: I cannot do your homework for you but can gladly share a help link.  Sounds like you may want an MDI Container form with child forms inside of it.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-mdi-child-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @RickDavin This is not homework it is a personal project I am working on.

Comment: Have you considered using a single form and hosting multiple user controls in it? Depending on the complexity, you could have all user controls loaded all the time and just call `BringToFront` on the "current page", otherwise you can add and remove the desired user control as needed.

Comment: You could even use a `TabControl` and just hide the tabs. You can then just set the `SelectedTab` or `SelectedIndex` to display the appropriate `TabPage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you only want to use Forms, then you need to modify the constructor of the child form to like:

```
public Classes()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    this.ControlBox = false;
}
```

And also call the child Form like:

```
private void btnclick_nxtpage(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
    var classes_Nxt = new Classes();
    classes_Nxt.MdiParent = this;
    classes_Nxt.Show();
    classes_Nxt.BringToFront();
    classes_Nxt.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;    
}
```

**Explanation:**

This code in the constructor is used to hide the child form's title bar, and we set the child's to `DockStyle.Fill` so that it can fill the parent form here. Regarding data sharing the easiest solution is to use the Singleton Pattern if the number of forms is little. If the application is large then I would recommend using shared classes or passing data through parameters of public methods between forms.

**Demo:**

[image]

**Personal Opinion:**

Personally, I think it is better to use the **Singleton UserControl** as the page you are referring to. The reason is that you can use them like panels and singleton because you can access all the object data at any given time. Also mostly only one such type of page is displayed so it is feasible. For large applications, you will just need to dispose of the objects properly.